# Making a single animation script control the bool conditions of several different Unity objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to script a text animation for my Android game, which should set an appropriate bool (numbered 1 to 5) true when a certain score is achieved, which then animates a text over the screen.

I created the animation clips for each text object (it's actually a 3D mesh) and gave each one of them the same script which uses a "SetBool" call for each numbered bool under its appropriate if condition.

When I put it only on the first text object and start the player (the condition for the first bool is immediately met) it moves the text as intended. But when I put the code on all of the text objects it returns a message that "bool1" doesn't exist (as only the first text object's animation has it) and the animation stops working. So I tried creating the same set of numbered bools for each of the text objects, just so they exist, but it still doesn't work.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost know what you're talking about.  Probably why you haven't gotten any responses.  But does your script have all the bools or just one per object? Is their an animator trigger that's not defined? Or is only 1 defined?  Is their an animator?  What's this script look like?

Comment: @jiveturkey It has a SetBool function for each bool that I created on the animation clips. So each clip has one bool and the script recalls all of them. But the the sams script is put on all text objects.

Comment: If you are asking how to set a variable in a bunch of objects at once, you could try `class SharedBool { public bool shared; public SharedBool( bool value ) => shared = value; public static implicit operator bool ( SharedBool self ) => self.shared; }` and then have that instance in all of your objects and manage the `shared` bool in the animator.